# Append number from input to href

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to append the number from an input field to the URL in a link.

My code at the moment is replacing the entire URL instead of adding to the end of it:

```html
<input id='customquantity' type='number'></input>
<a href="/product/?add-to-cart=46551" id='url'>Add To Basket</a>

<script>
  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#customquantity').keyup(function(){
      var quantity = jQuery('#customquantity').val();
      jQuery('#url').attr('href', '&quantity= ' + quantity);
    });
  });
</script>
```

If someone enters `'3'` into the input, the `href` becomes:

```html
href="&quantity=3"
```

instead of:

```html
href="/product/?add-to-cart=46551&quantity=3"
```

Can someone explain where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Currently you are seeting the url=&quantity= instead of the entire url. So it should be /product/?add-to-cart=46551&quantity=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command:

```
jQuery('#url').attr('href', '&quantity= ' + quantity);
```

Will change the element's href attribute, not append to it. To append, you would need to do:

```
var href = jQuery('#url').attr('href'); // Get the current href
jQuery('#url').attr('href', href + '&quantity= '+ quantity);
```

Note however, that this will keep appending to the href every single time the function runs. Here is the full approach I would take:

```
<input id='customquantity' type='number'></input>
<a href="/product/?add-to-cart=46551" data-basehref="/product/?add-to-cart=46551" id='url'>Add To Basket</a>

<script>
  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#customquantity').keyup(function(){
      var quantity = jQuery('#customquantity').val();
      var href = jQuery('#url').attr('data-basehref');
      jQuery('#url').attr('href', href + '&quantity= ' + quantity);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Explanation: Add the original href that you want to append to as a base-attribute, then every time you want to change it, do it based on that value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the original value and append your change onto the end:

```
  jQuery(function(){
    let url = jQuery('#url').attr('href');
    jQuery('#customquantity').keyup(function(){
      var quantity = jQuery('#customquantity').val();
      jQuery('#url').attr('href', url + '&quantity= ' + quantity);
    });
  });
```

Comment: This will add the quantity parameter multiple times if you change the input value.

Comment: This keeps appending to the URL every time. If I enter 2 then change my mind and enter 3 you get &quantity=2&quantity=3 instead of just &quantity=3

Comment: @NuclearApe Updated. Move the getting of the href out of the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`URL.searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) api to modify the `search` property of the `<a>`

Also note using `input` event so as to capture numbers incremented with arrow toggles as well as paste and key events

```js
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#customquantity').on('input', function(){
      var quantity = jQuery(this).val();
      
      jQuery('#url').prop('search', function(){
         var params = new URL(this.href).searchParams;
         params.set('quantity', quantity);
         return params;            
      });
      // demo log only
      console.log(jQuery('#url').prop('search'))
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='customquantity' type='number'></input>
<a href="/product/?add-to-cart=46551" id='url'>Add To Basket</a>
```